# Serialized data in database - how to echo, filter and format it with php?

Tags: php, sql, json, serialization

I hope I asked the question correctly on this one, I am not familiar with serialize/unserialize function at all.

1) I have a database table '**data**' with a field called '**demo_data**'. Each field containes a bunch of random characteres and the strings are very, very long. Example: 4fh7fjks2u839dk... (...) I have realized that in order to display the content of this field, data must be first procesed with the unserialize function (see step 2).

2) Function is like this:

unserialize definition:

```
function unserialize($data) {
    if (is_serialized($data)) {
        return @unserialize($data);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

call unserialize function:

```
function display_demo_data() {
    return unserialize(base64_decode(data_field('demo_data')));
}
```

3) Above functions DO work (tested, entire script is huge and not written by myself)

4) The important part: calling the data stored in the 'demo_data'

```
<?php echo display_demo_data(); ?>
```

and I correctly get the stored values:

```
{"value_min":0,"value_max":0,"sString":"demo"}
```

As you can see, this is very unpleasent for the end user. What I want? I want the data to be properly formatted, like this:

```
Value (Min): 0
Value (Max): - I wish to discard this values and info from echo call
sString: Demo
```

Does anyone know to format/filter returned data?

thanks,
dev101

Comment: Uhh... you are re-defining `unserialize()` as a recursive function to itself if the data is serialized. This is going to cause an infinite recursion and then a... \*puts on sunglasses\* Stack Overflow. ***YYYYEEEEEEAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH***

Comment: As I said, it works properly, I have missed some important stuff probably, but I cannot copy entire script here...

Comment: Hrmm... is your `unserialize()` function a class method? That's the only way I can see that not throwing a fatal error.

Comment: Hi Sammitch, as I stated above, I have absolutely no knowledge about this functions. But, you are probably right. That was all the code i could find that is connected to serial/unserial stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return is json_encoded.

```
$foo = '{"value_min":0,"value_max":0,"sString":"demo"}';
var_dump(json_decode($foo));
```

Asuming that `display_demo_data()` return the json, you would do:

```
<?php
$value = json_decode(display_demo_data());
?>
```

After that you can use the $value object to print your data. For example:

```
<?php
   print $value->value_min;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, probably its is, there are a lot of json stuff in this script (sorry to mention this, I dont know this stuff too much).

So, I have to put those lines exactly where?

Comment: Thanks everyone trying to help, trouble is that values 0,0,demo are dynamic and different for each user, I do not know them! This is why I try to get them from database in the first place. Still no results.

Comment: So... Do you see any hard values in the examples 2 and 3?

Comment: Here is what is going on: this is a serialized string of what user searched. It containes search keyword and many other fields. It is encoded in db and I try to pull that keyword on user's profile (sString). I have trouble with your first line, don't know where to put it and generally this does not work (either as if function does not exist, or it returns old data as in original question with bunch of data in a single line). Hope this will help a bit. Your first line contains search results like 0,0,demo -- and this is a dynamic value.

Comment: The first snippet is to show you that your data is `json_encoded`. Snippet two and three are the once you can use in your code. Replace `$value->value_min` for `$value->sString` to return the string.

Comment: Michal thanks for your help, but I still didn't solve this. I don't know where to put any of that code, inside my functions.php file or my user's php file (the display part), header or body. It does not work wherever I have tried, probably because my wrong placement of the code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hey Michal, I finally got it!!! Trouble was that the first snippet above was not needed at all ( $foo = '{"value_min":0, etc... ) since the function was already decoding, and that was making all the confusion. I deleted those lines and voila - it works!

Thanks again,
dev101

Answer (score 0):

If its JSON data you can decode it like

```
$returnValue = json_decode('{"value_min":0,"value_max":0,"sString":"demo"}');
```

And use

```
$returnValue -> value_min;

$returnValue -> value_max;

$returnValue -> sString;
```

Comment: Thanx Ajeet, can you please tell me where exactly I have to put this code? In php echo part, or the second function ('call' in my original question, as i named it).

thanks